# How to convert datatable from UDF in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This Codes give me error:
**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DefaultActivity, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure DefaultActivity, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@returnTable".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure DefaultActivity, Line 18
Must declare the table variable "@returnTable".**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DefaultActivity
RETURNS
    @returnTable table (
[VisitingCount] int,
[Time] nvarchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int
set @DateNow='00:00'
set @i=1;

    while(@i<1440)
        begin
            set @DateNow=DATEADD(minute, 1, @DateNow)
                insert into @returnTable ([VisitingCount], [Time]) values(0, right(left(convert(nvarchar, @DateNow, 121), 16), 5))
            set @i=@i+1
        end

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DefaultActivity ()
RETURNS @returnTable 
TABLE 
(
  [VisitingCount] int,
  [Time] nvarchar(50)
) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int

    set @DateNow='00:00'
    set @i=1;

    while(@i<1440)
        begin
                set @DateNow=DATEADD(minute, 1, @DateNow)
                insert into @returnTable ([VisitingCount], [Time]) 
                values(0, right(left(convert(nvarchar, @DateNow, 121), 16), 5))
                set @i=@i+1
        end

    RETURN
END

GO

select * from dbo.DefaultActivity()
```

Comment: @ykaratoprak - the question was answered correctly by Andomar as well (you only needed to add brackets) He did not post the full code though

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying an empty argument list?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DefaultActivity()
RETURNS
...
```

Comment: that's it - but it seems the OP needed a "copy and paste" solution

Comment: +1. Your solution is correct, I just ran the entire thing to make sure no other errors were made.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DefaultActivity()
RETURNS                    -- RETURN vs RETURNS here
```

Comment: i change it. but result is as same as before.